# Nondegenerate triangle of zero area. How is it possible?

Tags: geometric-construction, infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

I read book "A primer of infinitesimal analysis" John Bell. I was confused when I saw example with area under curve. In that example author mentioned about nondegenerate triangle of zero area. But triangle of zero area is degenerate triangle.

[image]

How is it possible? How to imagine what author meant in that example?

Thanks.

Comment: It rests on the existence of numbers $c\ne0$ such that $c^2=0$. In the real numbers, there is no such thing. But the author must be working in some number system where there are such things.

Comment: As said by (b) in the picture, there is an nonzero length whose square (i.e. area) is zero.

Comment: "*Infinitesimal analysis*"  The triangle is degenerate in so far as all of the vertices are *practically* the same point however in this context the author emphasizes that they are not literally the same points and there is a nonzero, albeit infinitesimal, distance between them.

Comment: Infinitesimals have been used to argue in calculus since the days of Newton and Leibniz (I have heard claims that even the Ancient Greeks dabbled in the subject). It is difficult to make rigorous, but that hasn't stopped people from using them intuitively.

Comment: By "non-degenerate triangle" the author may merely mean a triangle that three defined angles, none of which is zero. In standard analysis, such a triangle must have non-zero area, but on this page we are accepting many things that are impossible in standard analysis, such as two points that are indistinguishable but do not coincide. Phrases such as "patently incompatible with the law of excluded middle" should be a signal that things are going to be weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What makes this possible is intuitionistic logic.  The law of excluded middle is not accepted.  In particular, it cannot be proved that every number is either zero or nonzero.  There is a gray area where neither can be proved.  Nilsquare infinitesimals are in this gray area.  Thus, if $\epsilon$ is a nilsquare infinitesimal of Smooth Differential Geometry (SDG), then one can prove that $\epsilon^2=0$ but one cannot prove that $\epsilon$ itself is zero (nor can one prove that it is nonzero, as mentioned above).  Thus, by definition a square of side $\epsilon$ will have area $\epsilon^2=0$.  If you divide such a square by a diagonal, you get a pair of right-angle infinitesimal triangles that look perfectly ordinary except that their area is zero :-)

It used to be thought that it is difficult to make infinitesimals rigorous, but there are now axiomatic approaches conservative over ZF where one has [effective infinitesimals](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/spot.html) (the latter approach has nothing to do with SDG).

Comment: Does triangle with zero area exist even when we use classical approach with infinitesimals? For example, let $dy = 2xdx + (dx)^2$. We discard $(dx)^2$ and obtain $2xdx$ as result. Do we have at this stage rectangle which area is $2xdx$ and triangle of zero square under graph of function $y=2x$? Thanks.

Comment: Every standard nondegerate triangle has nonzero area, therefore every triangle in NSA has nonzero area, as well, by the transfer principle.  Therefore such phenomena don't arise in NSA. @Mike_bb

Comment: Note that multiple *comments* under your question speak of "nonzero infinitesimals".  This is an error since, as mentioned in my *answer*, $\epsilon$ is not provably nonzero.  Indeed, if one could prove that an infinitesimal is nonzero, one could also invert it, in which case it could not be nilsquare.

Comment: $\varepsilon$ is nilsquare and $\varepsilon$ is indistinguishable from zero as mentioned in the book.

Comment: John Bell also wrote that "XS is nondegenerate of length $\varepsilon$". @Mikhail Katz